# Automatically Download chromedriver that supports the currently installed version of chrome

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download Chromedriver into the current directory. I've tried chromedriver-auto installer and get_chrome_driver library. But, I can't download it into the specific directory.

This is my code.

```
from get_chrome_driver import GetChromeDriver

get_driver = GetChromeDriver()
get_driver.auto_download(extract=True, output_path="")
```

and I got this

```
PS D:\Project\Python\Automation\Socinet> & C:/Python37/python.exe d:/Project/Python/Automation/Socinet/chromedriver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Project/Python/Automation/Socinet/chromedriver.py", line 4, in <module>
    get_driver.auto_download(extract=True, output_path="")
TypeError: auto_download() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_path'
PS D:\Project\Python\Automation\Socinet>
```

What should I do?

Comment: im using webdriver_manager...`pip install webdriver_manager` and use it `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager` `driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run:

```
pip install get-chrome-driver --upgrade
```

then give dot if you want to download to currrent directory

```
get_driver.auto_download(extract=True, output_path=".")
```

Comment: Stopped working with google chrome Version 102.0.5005.115: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

> **You could use this solution. It will do two things:**
>
> 1. Check locally in your computer for the driver version and compare
>    it with the latest version available online.
> 2. The latest online version will be **downloaded** if it does not match your local version.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import zipfile
import wget
import subprocess
import os


CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "" # Insert your Chromedriver path here
CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
LATEST_DRIVER_URL = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"


def download_latest_version(version_number):
    print("Attempting to download latest driver online......")
    download_url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + version_number + "/chromedriver_win32.zip"
    # download zip file
    latest_driver_zip = wget.download(download_url, out=CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER)
    # read & extract the zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(latest_driver_zip, 'r') as downloaded_zip:
        # You can chose the folder path to extract to below:
        downloaded_zip.extractall(path=CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER)
    # delete the zip file downloaded above
    os.remove(latest_driver_zip)


def check_driver():
    # run cmd line to check for existing web-driver version locally
    cmd_run = subprocess.run("chromedriver --version",
                             capture_output=True,
                             text=True)
    # Extract driver version as string from terminal output
    local_driver_version = cmd_run.stdout.split()[1]
    print(f"Local driver version: {local_driver_version}")
    # check for latest chromedriver version online
    response = requests.get(LATEST_DRIVER_URL)
    online_driver_version = response.text
    print(f"Latest online chromedriver version: {online_driver_version}")
    if local_driver_version == online_driver_version:
        return True
    else:
        download_latest_version(online_driver_version)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will download your the most recent Chrome Driver

```html
import requests
import zipfile
import os
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from tqdm import tqdm
from pathlib import Path

def get_latest_chromedriver_version():
    url = 'https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    download_link = soup.find('a', {'id': 'chromedriver2win32'})
    version_text = download_link.text.strip().split()[-1]
    return version_text

def download_chromedriver(version, download_path):
    base_url = 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
    platform_name = 'win32' if platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' else 'win64'
    download_url = urljoin(base_url, f'{version}/chromedriver_{platform_name}.zip')

    response = requests.get(download_url, stream=True)
    total_size_in_bytes = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    block_size = 1024
    progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_size_in_bytes, unit='iB', unit_scale=True)

    with open(download_path, 'wb') as file, tqdm(
        desc=download_path,
        total=total_size_in_bytes,
        unit='B',
        unit_scale=True,
        unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for data in response.iter_content(block_size):
            progress_bar.update(len(data))
            bar.update(len(data))
            file.write(data)

    progress_bar.close()
    if total_size_in_bytes != 0 and progress_bar.n != total_size_in_bytes:
        print("ERROR, something went wrong")

def main():
    version = get_latest_chromedriver_version()
    download_dir = Path.cwd() / 'chromedriver'
    download_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    download_path = download_dir / 'chromedriver.zip'

    print(f"Downloading ChromeDriver version {version}")
    download_chromedriver(version, download_path)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(download_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(download_dir)

    os.remove(download_path)
    print(f"ChromeDriver version {version} downloaded and extracted to {download_dir}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

or

```html
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

def main():
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
    print("ChromeDriver installed successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```